# Filter by meta values order is not working

Tags: wordpress

I have created Custom Post Type - Event. Each Event has meta value date - 2013-11-27.

```
$event_list = get_posts(array(
    'post_type'     => 'event',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'orderby' => 'meta_date',
    'order' => 'DESC'               
));
```

When I output the date I get this order of event, which is not correct.

```
2013-05-14
2012-10-10
2013-11-04
2013-11-20
2013-11-27
```

But I need to get

```
2013-11-27
2013-11-20
2013-11-04
2013-05-14
2012-10-10
```

'order' => 'DESC' is not working. Am i doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have missed one parameter, please try below code::

```
$event_list = get_posts(array(
    'post_type'     => 'event',
    'meta_key'         => 'meta_date',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'DESC'               
));
```

Thanks

Comment: You can also do this by voting up rather than saying thanks... ;)